# MySQL DB connection issue using the sqlcmd client from the linux box

Tags: mysql

When i tried connecting to a MySQL DB server through the sqlcmd client, I am getting the below error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: ... : Login timeout expired.
>
> Sqlcmd: Error: ... : A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Can someone please help me out on this?

**Edit**:
To add, the instance name and the Server name are correct. Same goes with the Password and the username

Comment: To add; the instance name and the Server name are correct. Same goes with the Password and the username.

Comment: Possibilities are: 1. the server is not up, 2. server is firewall protected, 3. port is not open, etc. But with the error stack statements, I believe the server is not up. Check it again.

Comment: @ravinder reddy
I checked the server and it's up and running. Can you please let me know how to check on if the firewell is up or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer-
I was lucky to get an answer to this question through some different portal.
in this kind of issues we can use the port number next to the server name and that will resolve the issue.